# nothing show up in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-5

I want to make a web application that uses a laravel framework and vue.js after I have made the necessary settings and added the framework,  and linked the two files, and run the browser noting show up.

home.vue

```
<template>
    <div>

        <h1>zakaria sassi</h1>
    </div>
</template>
```

welcome.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Laravel</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,600" rel="stylesheet">


    </head>
    <body>
       <div id="app">
       <home></home>
       </div>

       <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer ></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');


Vue.component(
'home',
  require('./components/home.vue'));


const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
});
```

webpack.mix.js

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');


mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Comment: Whats on your routes/web.php? Whats your url?

Comment: Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Comment: Do you add /public on your url?

Comment: http://localhost:8081/vueapp/public/

Comment: same problem nothing showing up